# jQuery Detect Change of Input on Page Load by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my page I have a jQuery snippet:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#URL").on("input load", function(e) {
        console.log(e.type)
        ....
    });
});
```

lower on the page I have..

```
<input id="URL" type="text" value="<?=$_GET['URL'];?>">
```

to set the value to the `$_GET['URL']` value if it is set.

For some reason, the jQuery is never triggered unless I go and change the input.

Is there a way to have the jQuery trigger when I set the value via PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger input change **on load**:

```
$("#URL").trigger('input');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need trigger an action like input, for example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var fn = function(e) {
        console.log(e.type)
        //...
        $("body").append("<p>"+e.type+"</p>")

    };

    $("#URL").on("input", fn);
    $("#URL").on("load", fn);
    //Force the execution on load
    $("#URL").trigger('input');

});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andersoncontreira/u8jLpj1g/3/